# How to set map slots to work on a fixed blocks in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in Hadoop. I wonder to know how can I change the map assignment in Hadoop. for example, I want to always map slot on machine 1 processes the first block and map slot on machine 2 processes the second block and so on. how this is possible. thanks

Comment: Can you describe what your **actual problem** is?

Comment: I just want to know before process that which machine will process which block. just this